# Colorbox not displaying images in center of viewport

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using the jQuery plugin Colorbox for some images on [this site](http://whitefenceindustries.com). Select Rentals, 1.5 Bedrooms.

If you scroll around and click on the thumbnail images, you will notice that Colorbox is drifting the images either above or below - never in the exact center. I've tried different settings with 'top' and 'left' with no luck.

Is there a setting I can use so that no matter where you scroll in the page, Colorbox will display the images in the exact center of the viewport?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to write this in the answer section but I can't comment as of yet (requires 50 reps).

It seems the page (rentals > 1.5 bedrooms) is an iframe, right? Given that the colorbox only overlays the column, and per Firebug, I'd have to start with this being some if not all of the issue.

It looked to me like the pics were always 'drifting' into the exact center of your IFRAME, not viewport.I suspect the iframe is the issue.